# Gradle error when building the android-support-test project

Tags: android-testing

I'm trying to build the Android Support Testing project. I'm following [these instructions](http://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/contribute/index.html). I've got my build env setup and I've synced the Repo. When I try to build the project I get this error.

```
$ pwd
/Volumes/android/android-support-test

$ ls -l
-r--r--r--   1 me  staff    87 Feb  5 12:56 Makefile
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff   749 Feb  5 16:14 android-support-test.iml
drwxr-xr-x  11 me  staff   374 Feb  5 12:56 build
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff    31 Feb  5 12:57 build.gradle -> frameworks/testing/build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x  16 me  staff   544 Feb  5 12:57 external
drwxr-xr-x   4 me  staff   136 Feb  5 12:57 frameworks
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff   102 Feb  5 16:14 gradle
-r-xr-xr-x   1 me  staff  5884 Feb  5 12:57 gradlew
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff    35 Feb  5 12:57 local.properties -> frameworks/testing/local.properties
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff   102 Feb  5 16:17 out
drwxr-xr-x   7 me  staff   238 Feb  5 12:57 prebuilts
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff    34 Feb  5 12:57 settings.gradle -> frameworks/testing/settings.gradle

$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Volumes/android/android-support-test/frameworks/testing/build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-support-test'.
> Could not read script '/Volumes/android/android-support-test/version.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.31 secs
```

The `version.gradle` file is in `/Volumes/android/android-support-test/frameworks/testing`  but `build.gradle` is looking for it in `/Volumes/android/android-support-test`.

I think the aliasing of `build.gradle -> frameworks/testing/build.gradle` is not working correctly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `frameworks/testing` Repo project should have contained an additional sym link, but you can just create it yourself:

```
ln -s frameworks/testing/version.gradle version.gradle
```

h/t to John Lombardo [on the Android Testing Support Library google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-testing-support-library/SqWxM8NUxfk/sei6Dt1JBwAJ)